# put div as position absolute, ignoring all the parent divs seted as position absolute too

Tags: css

How is it possible, with all `<div>` seted as `position: absolute;` , bring an outsider class `<div>` to the front of all the others?
In this example, how can the `.free-object` (yellow), which is inside `.left` , overlap `.left` and `.right` ?

I tried controlling with `z-index:` but it's not working.

Remove the `overflow: auto;` is not a solution because i need to scroll it if the `.left` content pass the 100vh height.

**Reminder:** all `<div>` are set to `position: absolute;` , and `.free-object` will be called inside `.left`;

```css
body, html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
div.container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.container div.left {
  margin-left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

div.container div.right {
  margin-left: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orchid;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}

div.free-object {
  top: 20px;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: khaki;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"> 
    <div class="free-object"></div>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

If i put the **HTML** that way, it will work, but i need to call `div.free-object`, inside the `div.left`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="free-object"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I can see, if all divs are positioned absolute then this isn't possible (but I hope I'm wrong!). There's some discussion of this here: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow` property from the `div.left` element

```css
body, html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
div.container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.container div.left {
  margin-left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

div.container div.right {
  margin-left: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orchid;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
}

div.free-object {
  top: 20px;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: khaki;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"> 
    <div class="free-object"></div>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
    <p>line</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, but i need the overflow to scroll if the content of the `div.left` pass the 100vh height.